# File systems and the boot parameter block:

Tags: fat32

I read a tutorial about writing a bootloader. The author gave this as an example of a boot parameter block:

```
bootsector:
 iOEM:          .ascii "DevOS   "    # OEM String
 iSectSize:     .word  0x200         # bytes per sector
 iClustSize:    .byte  1             # sectors per cluster
 iResSect:      .word  1             # #of reserved sectors
 iFatCnt:       .byte  2             # #of FAT copies
 iRootSize:     .word  224           # size of root directory
 iTotalSect:    .word  2880          # total # of sectors if over 32 MB
 iMedia:        .byte  0xF0          # media Descriptor
 iFatSize:      .word  9             # size of each FAT
 iTrackSect:    .word  9             # sectors per track
 iHeadCnt:      .word  2             # number of read-write heads
 iHiddenSect:   .int   0             # number of hidden sectors
 iSect32:       .int   0             # # sectors for over 32 MB
 iBootDrive:    .byte  0             # holds drive that the boot sector came from
 iReserved:     .byte  0             # reserved, empty
 iBootSign:     .byte  0x29          # extended boot sector signature
 iVolID:        .ascii "seri"        # disk serial
 acVolumeLabel: .ascii "MYVOLUME   " # volume label
 acFSType:      .ascii "FAT16   "    # file system type
```

If I am using a **FAT32** file system can I just change the last part `(acFSType: ascii “FAT16 “)` and use this boot parameter block? If not where can I get a boot parameter block for **FAT32**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Mike Saunders ( the author of Mike-OS) in an email and his answer was no. I can't use this table for FAT32 just by changing that `(acFSType: ascii “FAT16 “)`part. To get a boot parameter block for the FAT32 file-system he sent me [this link to the Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463084).